# How to position an element just off the top of the browser viewport using only css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position, viewport

I want an absolutely-positioned element to be just out of the browser window - just off the  top of the browser viewport. Note that I cannot provide an exact height of the specified element.

Can this be done? If not, using jQuery is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS:**

```css
#theElement {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 100%;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var $el = $('#theElement');

$el.css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '-' + $el.outerHeight()
});
```

Comment: mainly because I want it to be positioned just off the screen on the loading of the page, and then they will see the element move up if it was javascript.

Comment: @think123 - Why do you need it *just above*. Do you care if it's *way above*?

Comment: Well if it was way above, then it would take a long time for an animation to move it back down. Here, I went with `bottom: 100%`, but for some reason this doesn't work. Can you see why? http://jsfiddle.net/Q8udg/3/

Comment: @think... not hard to move it closer with script once you know it's height. Could set it 20000px offscreen and fix it later

Comment: @think123 - You have to use matching types. You should animate to `0%`: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8udg/5/

Answer (score 0):

If your element is at `body` level this should work:

```
#element {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
}
```